# Adsense in MediaWiki

Tags: google-adsense

I use MediaWiki version 1.32.0 with PHP 7.1.30 (cgi-fcgi) and MySQL 5.6.40-84.0-log.
I try to add Adsense advertisements to the site's header, sidebar and footer.

At first I considered the [Widgets](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Widgets) extension but then decided to find an extension-free way.

I used the following code but Google Adsense test seems not to recognize it (a general error is given that "Google couldn't recognize your ads").
In `LocalSettings.php` I putted:

```
$wgHooks['SiteNoticeAfter'][] = function(&$siteNotice, $skin) {
    $siteNotice .= <<< EOT
<script async src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90x"
data-ad-client="ca-pub-****************"
data-ad-slot="6440411535"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
EOT;
    return true;
};
```

<sub>Instead the `****************` is my pub_code.</sub>

What is likely to go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the basic script that allows my web site to communicate with the Adsense API to the `<head>` tag of my website by a nested `<script>` HTML tag.

After doing so I was asked to wait 3 days for site review, though one might not need that in the future.